# Select2.js attribute change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using the selection element in HTML code, and I am using select2.js for this dropdown process. I created one attribute for this and wherever required this function in that place I'm adding this attribute name. everything is working fine. but if I select or deselect anyone dropdown all other dropdown values also selecting or deselecting. but I need it should work specific dropdown only, how to fix this? anyone help me to fix this.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="ts-col-30 horizontal-scroll">
          <select class="form-control md-form-control" selected  multiple  name="select_project" id="filter_status"
            ng-init="localFilterValue.status = ''"
            ng-model="localFilterValue.status" select2
            enable-clear="true"
            placeholder="status">
            <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in case"
              value="{{key}}" ng-bind="value"></option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

this is my JS code:

```
if (attrs.selected) {
  element.select2().on("select2:open", function (e) {
    $(".select2-results").children().not(':last').remove();
    $(".select2-results").prepend('<span class="d-flex w-100"><button type="button" class="chosen-toggle select">Select all</button>' + '<button type="button" class="chosen-toggle deselect ml-auto">DeSelect all</button></span>');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.select', function () {
    element.children().prop("selected", "selected");
    element.trigger("change");
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.deselect', function () {
    element.val(null).trigger("change");
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code or a code snippet so that it's easy to debug. Also `select2` has changed in its new versions. Which version are you using?

Comment: @Sachin Bahukhandi I updated my question, can you please check it. I am using the Select2 4.0.8 version.

Comment: Still the code misses the details, please make it runnable like a code snippet. So that it is easy to find out what you are trying to figure out.

Comment: This is angular based, I tried to make it runnable but it has some issue for connecting all the files. if any other way is there to show to you?